# Python numpy: for-loop vector that replaces values with new values in a specific range

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I need to make a for-loop that has a vector as an input. The output should be a new vector that has new values which are the old ones sorted in a specific range and then returned as a value if they are in the range.

range: 0>x = 0 (every negative number will just be 0 e.g.), 1>x>0 = 1,  2>x>1 = 2

The range is a specific range, so not the ceil, but maybe 6>x>3.2, I have to choose my own range

So, if input vector is [1.7,0.2,-0.4]

It would return: [2,1,0]

How can I do this with numpy?

I had something like this in mind:

```
outputvector=np.zeros(len(vector))

for i in(len(vector)):
    vector[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
#condition 0>x = 0 (every negative number will just be 0 e.g.), 1>x>0 = 1, 2>x>1 = 2
res = []
for i in a:
    if i < 0:
        res.append(0)
    elif i > 0 and i < 1:
        res.append(1)
    elif i > 1 and i < 2:
        res.append(2)
```

```
#condition - 0.2>x = 0, 0.7>x>0.2 = 1, 1.3>x>0.7 = 2,
res = []
for i in a:
    if i < 0.2:
        res.append(0)
    elif i > 0.2 and i < 0.7:
        res.append(1)
    elif i > 0.7 and i < 1.3:
        res.append(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 

What if the range is 0.2>x = 0, 0.7>x>0.2 = 1, 1.3>x>0.7 = 2, so not necessarily just the ceil, but a specific range?

Comment: @pineapples, I have added the code according to your condition. But what if the number is greater than `1.3`. Could there be any condition for that or some default condition for any number not in any particular range?

Comment: Also what about the boundary conditions?